# Error when adding new products to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error

We are having an issue when we add new products. You cant search the product in the store and when you go directly to the url https://www.vikingtelecomsolutions.com/viking-e-30tf-ip-stainless-steel-touch-free-voip-entry-phone.html we get an error on the product page. We cant find the product in our catalog, we cant search for the product in the store either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your indexes and url rewrites. Looks like it's looping somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your var/session/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the following points regarding this products.

```
1] Visibility: catalog Search
2] Status: Enable
3] Stock: in_stock
4] Categories assig
5] Search Engine Optimization: Check valid URL... I think the front controller could not find the matching product path/url in the url_rewrite database table.
6] If all the above checkpoint is proper then run the reindexing commands to reflect in-frontend store. (php bin/magento indexer:reindex)
```